# Extract part of the data from a csv file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Problem**

Extract a block of data from a file.

**Description**

Python reads a file. If it finds a particular string, it starts copying  all the next lines into an output file (included this first line), until is 'switched off'. *The key-string is only in the first line.*

**An attempt**

```
with open ('messy.csv', 'rt') as filein, open('nice.csv', 'w') as fileout:  
    for line in filein:
      if 'string' in line:  
        start=0
        while start<20:
          fileout.write(line)
          start+=1
```

The problem of this code, of course, is that the line copied isn't actualized (it just repeats the first line). Would you help me to solve it? (don't actually need the complete solution)

Comment: Change the `while` to `if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
with open ('messy.csv', 'rt') as filein, open('nice.csv', 'w') as fileout:  
    copy_flag = False
    start=0
    for line in filein:
        if 'string' in line:  
            copy_flag = True
        if copy_flag and start < 20:
            fileout.write(line)
            start+=1
```

Comment: But string is only in the first line, would it work anyway? I think I should clarify that, sorry

Comment: Yes, it will. Did you try it?

Comment: Oh, yes, fine. But I cant understand this: when in the second line of the infile, the second conditional is false. Why does it work anyway?

Comment: The copy flag is set to True when the 'string' condition is met.(line 6) and if the flag is true and start is less than 20, line will be written to the output

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the *start* variable, so it will copy 20 lines (including the first), right?

The problem is that you only copy the first line, because it's the only one that contains the key and accepts the if condition. Try this:

```
with open ('messy.csv', 'rt') as filein, open('nice.csv', 'w') as fileout:
    copy = False  #Initializes as false because we still don't know if the key exists
    start = 0
    first = True  #Make sure that we only compare the first line

    for line in filein:
      if 'string' in line and first == True:  
        copy = True
      first = False
      if copy == True and start < 20:   #Now we know that the key exists, we copy 20 lines
        fileout.write(line)
        start += 1
```